# cookiecutter: none type for R scripts

Tags: r, cookiecutter

I am trying to build an R project template with cookiecutter. However, I am facing a problem with the `null` type in my json configfile.

Basically, I am building dataframes based on the columns that are available in my input dataframe (which I am setting via a configfile), something like this:

```r
df %>%
    select(
        {{cookiecutter.var1}},
        {{cookiecutter.var2}},
        {{cookiecutter.var3}}
)
```

Based on my input data, it is possible that one or more values are not present.

In case a variable is not defined (as an example `var3`, I could do something like this)

```r
df %>%
    select(
        var1,
        var2,
        NULL
)
```

which I would like to organize via my `cookiecutter.json` file.

```json
...
"var3": null,
...
```

However, this `null` value does not get translated to `NULL` as in R, but to `None` as in Python (which is not known in R of course).

Any idea how I can fix this so that my value is translated to `NULL` instead of `None` inside my R scripts?

Thank you very much.

Comment: you could define a constant `None <- NULL` for a "synonym" of sorts ... not sure if this will work, but at least you would not have the problem of `Error: object 'None' not found`.

Comment: Good idea, thank you for the hint. Just as a pointer for anyone with a similar problem, `tidyselect` suggests to use `all_of()` or `any_of()` as the selection of external vectors is deprecated since v. 1.1.0., i.e. `data %>% select(all_of(None))`.