# R: deprecation warning for external vectors in select statement

Tags: r, dplyr

I am dealing with several datasets from which I want to select variables if they exist.

I am using cookiecutter for my template generation, it looks more or less like this (related to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76154251/cookiecutter-none-type-for-r-scripts)).

```r
{{cookiecutter.df}} %>%
  select(
    {{cookiecutter.var1}},
    {{cookiecutter.var2}},
    {{cookiecutter.var3}},
    {{cookiecutter.var4}}
    )
```

If the variables are not available in this dataset, they are translated to a Python `None` type. Therefore, I am setting this variable to a `NULL` value.

Here is my question

```r
library(tidyverse)

None <- NULL

mtcars %>%
  select(
    mpg,
    None,
    cyl,
    None
  )
```

This gives me the following deprecation warning.

```
Warning message:
Using an external vector in selections was deprecated in tidyselect 1.1.0.
ℹ Please use `all_of()` or `any_of()` instead.
  # Was:
  data %>% select(None)

  # Now:
  data %>% select(all_of(None))

See <https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/faq-external-vector.html>.
```

What is the issue here and how can it be fixed? I tried to toy with `all_of()` and `any_of()` but did not manage to solve it.

Notice: The double use of the `None` variable in my example refers to two variables that are not available in my dataset, at least in this example.

I hope everything is clear and thank you! If not, I will try to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to answer your question as you didn't provide your expected outcome. We cannot know what your real data looks like and what you want to get from it.

If you want `select()` not to fail if a variable is not found, you should use `any_of()`:

```r
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  select(any_of(c("mpg", "cyl", "cookiecutter.var4"))) %>% 
  names()
#> [1] "mpg" "cyl"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

However, you unfortunately cannot use the unquoted syntax with this function.

Comment: Did you test your command? 

This gives me an error: Error in select(): ! Problem while evaluating `any_of("mpg", "cyl", "cookiecutter.var4")`.

Comment: Yes, I understand that I did not provide a dataset, therefore the example with the None variable and the mtcars dataset. I would like to understand how I need to rewrite this mtcars example to avoid the deprecation warning.

Comment: Oh you are right I forgot a `c()` call. Here is the reprex. You should definitely use this package if you want more people to answer your questions BTW. Your example with the None is incomplete because you don't provide the expected output.